# Bubbling WPF control event in C#

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a custom control that essentially wraps a `ComboBox` and a `TextBox` into a custom `AutoCompleteTextBox`. I am attempting to bubble the `TextBox.TextChanged` event up to my custom control`AutoCompleteTextBox` so I can subscribe to the event as you would with any other event from a WPF by declaring the method to use for the subscriber in the XAML and instantiating that method in the code behind.

How do I make the `TextBox.TextChanged` event trigger a new event for `AutoCompleteTextBox` called, say, TextChanged so I can subscribe to `AutoCompleteTextBox.TextChanged`?

I have found a lot on MSDN about it but am having an issue relating it to my instance. Any help would be appreciated

The following is a stripped down version of the class that should provide all the necessary components related to what the class is the implementation of the `TextBox.TextChanged` event to trigger from.

```
   public partial class AutoCompleteTextBox : Canvas
{

    private VisualCollection controls;
    public TextBox textBox;
    private ComboBox comboBox;

    public AutoCompleteTextBox()
    {
        controls = new VisualCollection(this);

        // set up the text box and the combo box
        comboBox = new ComboBox();
        comboBox.IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem = true;
        comboBox.IsTabStop = true;
        comboBox.TabIndex = 1;

        textBox = new TextBox();
        textBox.TextWrapping = TextWrapping;
        if (MaxLength > 0)
        {
            textBox.MaxLength = MaxLength;
        }
        textBox.VerticalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Auto;
        textBox.VerticalContentAlignment = TextWrapping == System.Windows.TextWrapping.NoWrap ? System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Center : System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Top;
        textBox.TextChanged += new TextChangedEventHandler(textBox_TextChanged);
        textBox.TabIndex = 0;

        controls.Add(comboBox);
        controls.Add(textBox);
    }

    public int MaxLength { get; set; }

    private void textBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you can do that with routed events ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742806(v=vs.110).aspx ), as i remember if the textbox is in the same visual three, you can simply do in your AutoCompleteTextBox constructor: this.AddHandler(TextBox.TextChanged, new TextChangedEventHandler(yourMethodName)); Search for tutorials with wpf custom routed events

Comment: Hey John, I gave this a shot as well but it won't accept textbox.TextChanged because it is a TextChangedEventHandler and not a RoutedEventHandler.

Comment: try this: this.AddHandler(TextBox.TextChangedEvent, new TextChangedEventHandler(yourMethodName)); i havent typed it correctly, just copy pasted now from VS. With this handler you will intercept any text changed event from any textbox in your canvas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an new event to your control / class:

```
public event EventHandler<EventArgs> MyTextChanged;
```

In `textBox_TextChanged` do this:

```
if (MyTextChanged != null)
{
    MyTextChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

This can than be enhanced with your custom event args if you would like, etc.

If just named it *MyTextChanged* to mark what the new event is. You of course can name it *TextChanged*.

Comment: Perfect, that's exactly what I was looking for. It looks like I was just over complicating the process and mixing in custom event creation. Thanks.